# window.goldlog.record is not a function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am getting this error 'Uncaught TypeError: window.goldlog.record is not a function' When I was developing the Google plugin, and 'goldlog.record' is not in my code, I don't know where this code came from. Please help me.
This is a screenshot.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzDD4.png)

Comment: What do you get when you click the link to the file that caused the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the bottom error is the hint.

without seeing any code, my only guess is that method is provided by the script thats failing to load because it needs to be served over https.

either setup your workspace to use https or you could try running chrome with cors disabled something like:

[PATH_TO_CHROME]\chrome.exe" --disable-web-security

use the devtools element inspector to find the offending code, and continue debugging

Comment: Thank you very much, there is an interface across domains, I think I found the problem.